# Copy Tk Text Widget Contents Into A File

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to copy what is inside of a TK Text widget into a file.
What I mean by that is, copy all words and letters currently on the textbox and copy them into the file, so when I go into the file I will see what is in the textbox from the last time the program was run.
Here is my code: (some may have seen from earlier)

```
import datetime
from time import gmtime, strftime
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x800")
text1 = Label(root, text="Menu", font='Verdana, 15')
text1.pack()
coststr = StringVar()
cost = 0
coststr.set(f'£ {cost}')
menu = ["Burger", "Chips", "Milkshake"]
textln = Label(root, text="\n")
textln.pack()
day = datetime.date.today()



def choiceburger():
    global cost
    global coststr
    cost += 1.99
    cost = round(cost, 2)
    coststr.set(f'£ {cost}')
    txt.insert(END, 'Burger £1.99\n',)


def choicechips():
    global cost
    global coststr
    cost += 1.49
    cost = round(cost, 2)
    coststr.set(f'£ {cost}')
    txt.insert(END, 'Chips £1.49\n',)

def choicemilkshake():
    global cost
    global coststr
    cost += 0.99
    cost = round(cost, 2)
    coststr.set(f'£ {cost}')
    txt.insert(END, 'Milkshake £0.99\n',)



def pay():
    global cost
    global coststr
    txt.insert(END, "Total Charges: ")
    txt.insert(END, coststr.get())
    from tkinter import messagebox
    msgbox = messagebox.askokcancel("", "Are You Sure You Want To Buy These Items?")
    printrec()
    if msgbox == True:
        txt.delete('1.0', END)
        cost = 0
        cost = round(cost, 2)
        coststr.set(f'£ {cost}')
        txtboxmsg()
    else:
        quit()


burgerbutton = Button(root, text="    Burger   £1.99     ", command=choiceburger)
burgerbutton.pack()
chipsbutton = Button(root, text="    Chips   £1.49       ", command=choicechips)
chipsbutton.pack()
milksbutton = Button(root, text="  Milkshake   £0.99 ", command=choicemilkshake)
milksbutton.pack()

textln = Label(root, text="\n")
textln.pack()
textln = Label(root, text="\n")
textln.pack()
textln = Label(root, text="\n")
textln.pack()

txt = Text(root)
txt.pack()

def txtboxmsg():
    txt.insert(END, strftime("%H:%M:%S "))
    txt.insert(END, day)
    txt.insert(END, " Jake's Fast Food\n")


txtboxmsg()


def gettxt():
        inputt=txt.get("1.0","end-1c")
        print(inputt)

def printrec():
    f = open(r"F:/fast food code/receipts.txt", "a")
    f.write("\n{}\n".format(gettxt()))
    f.close()

costlabel = Label(root, textvariable=coststr, font='Verdana, 20')
costlabel.pack()
textln = Label(root, text="\n")
textln.pack()
paybutton = Button(root, text="Pay", command=pay, font='Verdana, 25')
paybutton.pack()
textln = Label(root, text="\n")
textln.pack()
```

You can see that I have made a program that acts like a shop and prints a receipt once done. I want to print that receipt (The Text Box, `txt`) into a file,  `F:/fast food code/receipts.txt`. Whenever I save the receipt into the file, I go inside of the file to have a look and I all I get is 'None' as if nothing was saved into the file, which it clearly was.

To Make it clearer, my question is how can I copy the contents of my Text widget directly into a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning the `inputt` from the function. Try:

```
import datetime
from time import gmtime, strftime
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x800")
text1 = Label(root, text="Menu", font='Verdana, 15')
text1.pack()
coststr = StringVar()
cost = 0
coststr.set(f'£ {cost}')
menu = ["Burger", "Chips", "Milkshake"]
textln = Label(root, text="\n")
textln.pack()
day = datetime.date.today()



def choiceburger():
    global cost
    global coststr
    cost += 1.99
    cost = round(cost, 2)
    coststr.set(f'£ {cost}')
    txt.insert(END, 'Burger £1.99\n',)


def choicechips():
    global cost
    global coststr
    cost += 1.49
    cost = round(cost, 2)
    coststr.set(f'£ {cost}')
    txt.insert(END, 'Chips £1.49\n',)

def choicemilkshake():
    global cost
    global coststr
    cost += 0.99
    cost = round(cost, 2)
    coststr.set(f'£ {cost}')
    txt.insert(END, 'Milkshake £0.99\n',)



def pay():
    global cost
    global coststr
    txt.insert(END, "Total Charges: ")
    txt.insert(END, coststr.get())
    from tkinter import messagebox
    msgbox = messagebox.askokcancel("", "Are You Sure You Want To Buy These Items?")
    if msgbox == True:
        printrec()
        txt.delete('1.0', END)
        cost = 0
        cost = round(cost, 2)
        coststr.set(f'£ {cost}')
        txtboxmsg()
    else:
        quit()


burgerbutton = Button(root, text="    Burger   £1.99     ", command=choiceburger)
burgerbutton.pack()
chipsbutton = Button(root, text="    Chips   £1.49       ", command=choicechips)
chipsbutton.pack()
milksbutton = Button(root, text="  Milkshake   £0.99 ", command=choicemilkshake)
milksbutton.pack()

textln = Label(root, text="\n")
textln.pack()
textln = Label(root, text="\n")
textln.pack()
textln = Label(root, text="\n")
textln.pack()

txt = Text(root)
txt.pack()

def txtboxmsg():
    txt.insert(END, strftime("%H:%M:%S "))
    txt.insert(END, day)
    txt.insert(END, " Jake's Fast Food\n")


txtboxmsg()

def gettxt():
    inputt=txt.get("1.0",END)
    print(inputt)
    return inputt

def printrec():
    f = open(r"receipts.txt", "a")
    f.write("\n{}\n".format(gettxt()))
    f.close()

costlabel = Label(root, textvariable=coststr, font='Verdana, 20')
costlabel.pack()
textln = Label(root, text="\n")
textln.pack()
paybutton = Button(root, text="Pay", command=pay, font='Verdana, 25')
paybutton.pack()
textln = Label(root, text="\n")
textln.pack()
```

Comment: My mistake, it appears it does indeed work. Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in the `def gettxt():` function.

Change this:

```
def gettxt():
        inputt=txt.get("1.0","end-1c")
        print(inputt)
```

To this:

```
def gettxt():
    global txt
    inputt=txt.get("1.0","end-1c")
    print(inputt)
    return inputt
```

You could simply bypass this function by doing the work in `printrec()`.

Try this instead:

```
def printrec():
    global txt
    f = open(r"./receipts.txt", "a")
    f.write("\n{}\n".format(txt.get("1.0","end-1c")))
    f.close()
```

Your code has some other issues as well. Make sure you are using proper indention. In your `gettxt()` you have indented 8 spaces instead of 4. You also do not need to have spacers in your labels. You can use padding to get what you want.

For reference I have updated your code to a class and cleaned it up a bit.
This will prevent the need for global's and provide you some reference to what needs and doesn't need a variable name as well as how you can space things out with padding instead of adding more labels.

```
import datetime
from time import strftime
from tkinter import messagebox
# import tkinter as tk helps to prevent an accidental overriding of variable/function names in the namespace.
import tkinter as tk

# Using a class we can get rid of global and manage things much easier using class attributes
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry("500x800")
        # This weight helps the widgets in column 0 resize with the window.
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.coststr = tk.StringVar()
        self.cost = 0
        self.coststr.set('£ {}'.format(self.cost))
        self.menu = ["Burger", "Chips", "Milkshake"]
        self.day = datetime.date.today()
        #this label is using `pady` to set the padding below the widget so you do not need spacer labels
        tk.Label(self, text="Menu", font='Verdana, 15').grid(row=0, column=0, pady=(0, 20))        
        self.btn_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.btn_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)
        # These buttons are placed in a frame so they can expand to fit the frame and be all the same size.
        tk.Button(self.btn_frame, text="Burger: £1.99", command=self.choiceburger).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew")
        tk.Button(self.btn_frame, text="Chips: £1.49", command=self.choicechips).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
        tk.Button(self.btn_frame, text="Milkshake: £0.99", command=self.choicemilkshake).grid(row=2, column=0, pady=(0, 80), sticky="ew")

        self.txt = tk.Text(self)
        self.txt.grid(row=2, column=0)

        tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.coststr, font='Verdana, 20').grid(row=3, column=0, pady=(0, 40))
        tk.Button(self, text="Pay", command=self.pay, font='Verdana, 25').grid(row=4, column=0)

        self.txtboxmsg()

    def choiceburger(self):
        self.cost += 1.99
        self.cost = round(self.cost, 2)
        self.coststr.set('£ {}'.format(self.cost))
        self.txt.insert("end", 'Burger £1.99\n',)

    def choicechips(self):
        self.cost += 1.49
        self.cost = round(self.cost, 2)
        self.coststr.set('£ {}'.format(self.cost))
        self.txt.insert("end", 'Chips £1.49\n',)

    def choicemilkshake(self):
        self.cost += 0.99
        self.cost = round(self.cost, 2)
        self.coststr.set('£ {}'.format(self.cost))
        self.txt.insert("end", 'Milkshake £0.99\n',)

    def pay(self):
        self.txt.insert("end", "Total Charges: ")
        self.txt.insert("end", self.coststr.get())
        msgbox = messagebox.askokcancel("", "Are You Sure You Want To Buy These Items?")
        self.printrec()

        if msgbox == True:
            self.txt.delete('1.0', "end")
            self.cost = 0
            self.cost = round(self.cost, 2)
            self.coststr.set('£ {}'.format(self.cost))
            self.txtboxmsg()
        else:
            self.destroy()

    def txtboxmsg(self):
        self.txt.insert("end", strftime("%H:%M:%S "))
        self.txt.insert("end", self.day)
        self.txt.insert("end", " Jake's Fast Food\n")

    def printrec(self):
        # this with open statement will also close once the write is complete.
        with open(r"./receipts.txt", "a") as f:
            # this write statement gets the data directly from txt so you do not need the gettxt() function.
            f.write("\n{}\n".format(self.txt.get("1.0","end-1c")))

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: As I have answered , There is no need to make variables global. Just return the `inputt`.

Comment: @BlackThunder the global is explicit for a reason. The only reason your function is working without the global is because `txt` is not defined in the function so it then checks the global namespace for txt. It is nice that Python will do this but if you have global it is still better to declare them for maintainability and readability.

Comment: You are `print`ing `inputt` after returning. It will never print.

Comment: @BlackThunder. Ty fixed.